# Links posted to Facebook page with Twitter not previewing correctly

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have my Twitter account connected to my Facebook page. When a tweet is posted to Facebook, that also contains my website’s URL, Facebook picks a random image from my home page, and crops it badly. The description is also wrong, which is just the first handful of body characters that appear on my page, including the page title “Home”.

I have set a default image and description with `og:image` and `og:description` tags respectively. And the Open Graph Object Debugger correctly shows this meta data. Posting of this link in other areas of Facebook result in the correct link preview.

So why are the links of my tweets in Facebook so badly previewed? Could it be something to do with Twitter's URL shortener?

I really don't even need the preview as it's only a copy of a tweet. I'd be interested too if I could disable link previews somehow. But only for posted tweets.

Comment: Facebook open graph needs a bit more than a twitter URL. I found this out by giving up and making a FB app myself. You need to specify the URL, post content, description and image. Once you have all these things you can make a 'pretty' preview. Unfortunately this should all be able to be derived from your web page og tags... but they don't get read. Anyone else coming here may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php) useful for building their own FB poster app. I made it mimic my twitter account.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with Twitter rather than the `og:image` settings in your site.

I too have had this problem. If I share a link to my site directly on FB then the correct `og:image` is chosen and it is sized correctly. If however I share the same link on Twitter and use Twitter's build in facilities to share to Facebook, the correct `og:image` is shown in FB but it's horribly distorted and stretched.

For a while I thought it was the settings on my site but I tried this with links from other sites and the same happens.

I've tried contacting Twitter support but not had much luck.

Comment: The twitter->facebook link was poorly designed and broken for a lot of people until recently. They must have finally looked at it. Some things have changed since... like you can't have separate twitter accounts connected to different pages you manage. Maybe the page in its original form is loosing its header through the URL shortening and affiliate links somehow. I don't know. I don't see how facebook can't resolve the link like it would natively (if you posted it directly) if your browser can do it when clicking on it.